# open api 3 posting an array of files

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am using swagger hub to [create this API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/1.0); but it doesn't support multi files in the UI so I am unsure if I am doing this right

My goal is to have the following

```
item:{Json describe the item}
images[] = images for item posted as an array
titles[] = Parallel array to images that has the title for image
alt_texts[] = Parallel array to images that has the alt text for image
```

This has to be multipart since it is files; but am unsure if I setup the structure correctly.

Swagger/Open API Code

```
post:
  summary: Add a new item to the store
  description: ''
  operationId: addItem
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewItemWithImage'
    description: Item object that needs to be added to the store
    required: true


NewItemWithImage:
  type: object
  properties:
    item:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewItem'
    images[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        format: binary
    titles[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
    alt_texts[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
    variation_ids[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
  required:
    - item
```

Comment: Try using `type: file` for the field. See this https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254#issuecomment-280659457

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713477/how-to-upload-multiple-files-images-with-swagger-3-0-using-use-a-binary-string

Comment: I've ask a question on this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713477/how-to-upload-multiple-files-images-with-swagger-3-0-using-use-a-binary-string

Answer (score 7):

According to [File Upload](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) section in OpenAPI 3 specification:

**File Upload**

> Files use a `type: string` schema with `format: binary` or `format: base64`,
>   depending on how the file contents will be encoded.

**Multiple File Upload**

> Use the
>   multipart media type to define uploading an arbitrary number of files
>   (an array of files):

```yaml
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                filename:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
```

You current definition corresponds to the specification precisely:

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewItemWithImageUrl'
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewItemWithImage'

NewItemWithImage:
  type: object
  properties:
    item:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewItem'
    images[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        format: binary
    titles[]:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
    ...
```

Comment: This answer is awesome in term of OpenAPI specs, and it put me in the good path. But with Swagger, it does not send it with the correct standard to NodeJS like `req.files` or `req.body.titles` which should be an array. I'll have to figure this out with Swagger.

Answer (score 1):

The code for swagger-ui is failing as of today in curlify.js

```
        if (v instanceof win.File) {
          curlified.push( `"${k}=@${v.name}${v.type ? `;type=${v.type}` : ""}"` )
        } else {
          curlified.push( `"${k}=${v}"` )
        }
```

curlify.js is not taking the array into account and is sending:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:9122/upload-all" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "my-attachment=[object File],[object File]"`

and not something like:

`curl -X POST "https://foo/v1/api/upload/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "myfile=@bla;type=application/zip" -F "myfile=@foo;type=application/zip"`

Comment: The real problem is caused by the swagger-js library [that stringifies the parameter arrays](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/src/execute/oas3/build-request.js#L76) without checking if their values are of a more complex type like Files are. So curlify's curl function does not even get an array their but a stringified parameter already.

Comment: Anyway of solving this? Maybe I should add a couple of duplicate binary fields `myfile` instead of relying on Array type that Swagger can't convert

Comment: And of course, JSON won't accept duplicate keys. So I'm stuck with swagger ui. I think it's time they allow us to capture event on sending, and to hack some code before sending the requests.