# How do I specify a multifile upload in OpenAPI?

Tags: json, file-upload, swagger, multipartform-data, openapi

I am trying to generate the data to populate the OpenAPI 3.0 input from my codebase.

I have a rest endpoint that is for uploading files to the server.

I have a form as a polymer vaadin-upload component for uploading files.  The path is `/upload-all` and the form parameter name is `my-attachment`.  The form properly uploads files to the server, so that is not the problem.

The server endpoint is implemented using [XQRS RestXQ Uploading Files in HTML Forms](https://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/form-file-uploads) specification.

I am trying to create an OpenAPI JSON input for the OpenAPI 3.0 UI for the multipart file upload.  Here is what I have tried:

```
"/upload-all": {
    "post": {
        "consumes": ["multipart/form-data"],
        "description": "Upload zip file to the server",
        "responses": {
            "content": {
                "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "parameters": [
            {
                "in": "formData",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "file"
                    }
                },
                "name": "my-attachment"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

I am getting an error that the form parameter `my-attachment` is not being populated.  What am I missing?  I have not been able to find a definitive specification on the OpenAPI website.

UPDATE:
I tried changing the output of my code to:

```
"/upload-all": {
    "post": {
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {
                "multipart/form-data": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "my-attachment": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "format": "binary",
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "description": "Upload zip file to the server",
        "responses": {
            "content": {
                "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

And the OpenAPI UI shows the following:

[image: OpenAPI UI]

It should be something like:

[image: file uploads]

The OpenAPI UI is current and up to date.  What is missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open api 3 posting an array of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433984/open-api-3-posting-an-array-of-files)

Comment: The linked answer is YAML, but you can use https://www.json2yaml.com to convert it to JSON.

Comment: As for what's wrong with your original example - you are mixing OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0 syntax, e.g. `consumes` and `in: formData` are OpenAPI 2.0 keywords and are not used in 3.0. You might find this [OpenAPI 3.0 syntax guide](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/basic-structure/) helpful.

Comment: I updated the question with results of your recommendation, but am still having problems.

Comment: I got an email recently and it is apparently fixed.  Get the latest version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there - just add `"type": "object"` to your request body schema:

```json
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {
                "multipart/form-data": {
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object",   // <-------
                        "properties": {
                            "my-attachment": {
                                ...
```

Make sure you're using **Swagger UI v. 3.25.3 or later**. Earlier versions [did not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4600) multiple file upload.

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: It appears to send the binary, but not the mime type or filename.

Comment: curlify.js is not taking the array into account.  I tried compiling swagger-ui, but `npm install` failed, so I cannot fix the code myself.